# Angular 2: Observables destroy itself when navigating to another route

Tags: angular, observable, resolver

I have a question regarding observables and its subscription. Would an observable subscription destroy itself when navigating away from the page where the subscription is initiated?

Also, if resolvers are returning data from an observable, would I need to unsubscribe from that observable? I use the resolver data through the following syntax

```
    this.resolverData = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['resolver1'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, if you want to persist observable data between different states you need to include it in a service and inject that service into the relevant app module (higher on the component tree if you want more components to know about it etc)

2) If you want to end an observable stream intentionally, you can try the **dispose** method, or if you want to trigger an event when the observable stream ends or throws an exception, you can use the **finally** method.

I hope this answers both of your questions :)